# Как передать C# словарь в качестве аргумента в Python скрипт?

Tags: python, c#

Есть ли возможность при запуске процесса внутри C# передавать в качестве аргумента не просто строки, а коллекции, в частности, словари?

```
private Dictionary<string, string> toMethod = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
     { "Forward fill", "ffill" },
     { "Backward fill", "bfill" },
};
private void run_python(string cmd, string args)
{
     ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
     start.FileName = "my/full/path/to/python.exe";
     start.Arguments.Add(toMethod);  // Что-то подобное
     start.UseShellExecute = false;
     start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
     {
         using(StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
         {
             string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
             Console.Write(result);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Библиотеку IronPython поизучайте

Comment: У процесса кроме StandardOutput есть и StandardInput - вот туда пишите что хотите, а на стороне питона читайте из stdin

Comment: @aepot, Скрипт использует библиотеки, которые недоступны в IronPython